# terminal autocomplete when there are several files/directory?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, autocomplete

I've created a user using

```
sudo useradd -m peris
```

but when I log in the terminal, I use the tab to autocomplete, but its not working, and it is working in the root user

For instace I am in a folder where there are more folders like:

```
menus-can-peris
```

I type `me` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> but `menus-can-peris` is not autocompleted

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/sh
```

Comment: What shell is the `peris` user using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/bin/sh` shell in Ubuntu is `dash`, which does not support tab completion.

I suggest that you change the login shell for the `peris` user to a shell that *does* support tab completion of filenames, for example `bash`.

You change the login shell using the `chsh` command whilst logged in as the user, or with `chsh peris` as root. The new shell will be used for the next and subsequent logins.